# Component for current and voltage amplification

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, components

I have a first current-generating circuit that produces an adjustable source/sink current (between + 10 mA and - 10 mA) with an output voltage range of ± 10 V.

I want to amplify this current by a fixed value to reach ± 100 mA as well as increase the maximum voltage output to ± 100 V so that it can deliver this current in typical impedance conditions.

Designing a custom circuit for this is an option but I'm surprised that I can't find any off-the-shelf component that can perform this.

Am I missing something, is there any keyword that would be useful in this search or is just not something that exists off-the-shelf?

Comment: Precision current amplifiers are a bit non-main-stream. A voltage to current amplifier is a little more centre-stream so maybe you are beginning in the wrong place. I.e. start with a signal voltage and find a voltage to current amplifier (or design one).

Comment: @ThePhoton: true, I edited the post to add values.

Comment: [This article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-design-simple-voltage-controlled-bidirectional-analog-current-source/) on allaboutcircuits might help, but you will have to adapt it to allow for the +/-100 V outputs.

Comment: @Andyaka: it's indeed easier to find voltage to current amplifiers. The thing is I really have to work with the first circuit that is a current generator, however I could have a simple current-voltage conversion and then use a voltage to current amplifier, the trick is to find one that takes positive and negative values and outputs source/sink currents, but I'll look into it!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this behavioral model:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7oT8q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll leave the details of design to you, since you know your application space better. At such high compliance voltages and over such potentially high sink/source currents you will certainly have to do some thermal analysis and make adjustments. You'll also need to select appropriate BJTs that can stand off the required voltages (2N5550 and 2N5401 are examples having \$V_\text{CEO}=150\:\text{V}\$ but not necessarily the dissipation requirements.)

I use the above design with a smaller compliance range (\$\pm 60\:\text{V}\$) and for a much smaller range of currents. So I know it works fine.

And no, I do not know of an OTS option in IC form that handles even a \$\pm 80\:\text{V}\$ compliance range for \$-5\:\text{mA} \le I_O \le 5\:\text{mA}\$. If you find one, please let me know.